# Merge two dataframes based on column in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Two DataFrames (`df1`, `df2`), `df1` has column `ID` and `df2` has columns `ID, flag1, flag2`.

I want to merge two DataFrames where all the ID's in `df1` should be taken along with `flag1`,`flag2` values.

I have the following line of code.

```
df3=pd.merge(df1, df2, on=id, how='left')
```

The output of `df3` shows column values only for ID, and there are no values for `flag1` and `flag2`.

The expected result in `df3` should be `ID, flag1, flag2` with values for `flag1` and `flag2` from `df2`.

Comment: Should it be `on='ID'`? Also your merge code should be working as intended, unless there is no matched ID between the two dataframes.

Comment: can you add 2 samples of df1 and df2 which replicates your original dataframe? so we can understand better? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Then, simply:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [2,4,6],
                    'flag1' : ['a','b','c'],
                    'flag2' : ['aa','bb','cc']})

pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left')
```

**output**

```
   id   flag1   flag2
0   1   NaN NaN
1   2   a   aa
2   3   NaN NaN
3   4   b   bb
4   5   NaN NaN
5   6   c   cc
```

Comment: Hi, I tried ,but does not seems to be working. still not showing any values for flag1 and flag2.

Comment: Please, run my code and check the output. Do you get what I got?

Comment: Hi All, Issue is fixed. It was bacause of the datatype issue in ID column. One ID column is of type: object and other of int64.